# PGP KeyServers: Creating Personal Keyserver

Tags: 10.04, pgp

Is it possible to create your own PGP KeyServer on Ubuntu to host PGP keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/sks) to build your own keyserver. Here is a small [quick-start guide](http://serkadis.com/index/568142).

Comment: Is there any site where I can post questions in order to get debug support?

Comment: both links seem to be dead